# Image cropping from AWS Textract's analyze_expense method

Tags: python-3.x, image-processing, text-extraction, amazon-textract

When I am trying to crop images based on the polygon vertices -> resonse generated from analyze expense, some images are not getting cropped properly.

```
def vertices_fun(bucket_name, img_path):
    response = textract_client.analyze_expense(Document={'S3Object': {'Bucket': bucket_name, 'Name': img_path}})
    points = []
    for i in response['ExpenseDocuments'][0]['SummaryFields']:
        if i['Type']['Text'] == <some id>:
            points.append(i['ValueDetection']['Geometry']['Polygon'])
    return points

def vertices_to_pixels(vertices, img_width, img_height):
    pixel_vertices = []
    for vertex in vertices:
        x_pixel = int(vertex['X'] * img_width)
        y_pixel = int(vertex['Y'] * img_height)
        pixel_vertices.append((x_pixel, y_pixel))
    print("pixel vertices:")
    print(pixel_vertices)
    return pixel_vertices

def crop_image(bucket_name, img_path, vertices, output_folder, check):
    # Download image from S3
    img_obj = s3_client.get_object(Bucket=bucket_name, Key=img_path)
    img = Image.open(img_obj['Body'])
    img_width, img_height = img.size
    print("width: ",img_width)
    print("height: ",img_height)
    #img_height, img_width = img.size
    
    # Convert vertices from normalized coordinates to pixels
    pixel_vertices = vertices_to_pixels(vertices, img_width, img_height)
    
    # Calculate bounding box
    x_coords, y_coords = zip(*pixel_vertices)
    left = min(x_coords)
    upper = min(y_coords)
    right = max(x_coords)
    lower = max(y_coords)
    print(left, right, upper, lower)
    
    # Crop image
    cropped_img = img.crop((left, upper, right, lower))
    
    # Save cropped image to S3
    cropped_img_bytes = io.BytesIO()
    cropped_img.save(cropped_img_bytes, format='JPEG')
    
    # Upload cropped image to S3 in the specified output folder
    if(check == 0):
        cropped_img_key = f"{output_folder}/{img_path.split('/')[-1]}"
        s3_client.put_object(Bucket=bucket_name, Key=cropped_img_key, Body=cropped_img_bytes.getvalue())
    
        return cropped_img_key
    else:
        # if same id has been detected at mupltiple areas will create image folder containing         #image_versions 
        img_no, img_type = (img_path.split('/')[-1]).split('.')
        cropped_img_key = output_folder + '/' + img_no + '_' + check + '.' + img_type
        s3_client.put_object(Bucket=bucket_name, Key=cropped_img_key, Body=cropped_img_bytes.getvalue())
```

`return cropped_img_key`
is there something I am missing, found error pattern in jpg imgs, with different color backgrounds other than white, image text orientation